Bond-style film from the 60s or 70s: man 'signals' associate to honk car horn
I'm asking this question for someone else, but I promise I will be able to respond (possibly with a slight delay) to any requests for extra detail!
This was a James Bond style spy film (but not actually James Bond): live action, in colour, and from the 1960s or 1970s. It was in English, probably a Hollywood production, and was set on the west coast of the United States.
Towards the end of the film, in the final confrontation between the main 'good guy' and the main 'bad guy', the former tricks the latter into owning up to everything he's done. The bad guy does this because he knows he'll be able to shoot the good guy afterwards. However, the good guy then says he's been recording the whole conversation using a hidden microphone inside his watch. To prove it, he says "toot the car horn now" to his watch, and his associate in the car honks the horn.
However, in fact the good guy didn't have a hidden microphone - we'd already seen him instructing his associate earlier on to toot the car horn at a particular moment. But he timed everything so precisely that it seemed the toot was because of his instruction to the watch. His subterfuge startled the bad guy sufficiently that the good guy could overpower him, and there was a happy ending.

The two characters in the final confrontation were both white and male.
The associate in the car was white and female.
The car was a convertible.
The final confrontation took place on a beach.

I hope this is enough detail for someone to identify the film!

I remember this movie, but it's a dim light of recognition. I wish I had something for you.

Was this possibly a spoof, like those Dean Martin films? And could it have been a TV show?

@Walt Probably not a spoof; could possibly have been a TV show (do you have one that fits?)

@John Can confirm it's not The Quiller Memorandum.

@randal'thor No idea, sorry. It just sounded like something that might also happen on a show.

Maybe you can find something here? http://www.imdb.com/list/ls000380138/ Sorry I don't have time to search for your movie a little bit more, I can a more detailed answer if you find something =)

Was it one of the Matt Helm movies, starring Dean Martin? There were at least three of them: The Silencers, The Ambushers, and The Wrecking Crew. They were take-offs on James Bond movies, somewhere between Bond and Austin Powers. And they fit the parameters mentioned: live action, color, Hollywood production, West coast, the hero drives a convertible.

@Lakebum There was a fourth one - Murderers' Row - which appears to have taken place on a tropical island (high probability of scenes taking place on beaches.)  Unfortunately, I can't find any detailed synopsis or references to the watch gag.  I may have to track these films down and watch them anyway, though, so I'll follow up if it looks like a match.

@Steve-O Let me know if you find anything there! It's frustrating that this question got so many votes yet has gone unanswered for so long ...

Sound familiar, I'm thinking it might be the Domino Effect, I'm searching for proof.

Sorry, was thinking of The Domino Principle, but that's not it. Now you got me intrigued, because it feels familiar as well.

The two main Bond style movies were Matt Helm (mentioned above) or Flint.  Althought Murder's Rows final scene is on an island, Helm's female accomplice is a redhead not a blond and the poster would surely have recalled the hovercraft chase scene.  Because the plot outline given is one of being low budget (no expensive fantastic bas explosion sequence climax) and rather "lame", I would suggest the higher probability of it being the TV movie produced by  20th Century Fox Television for ABC, filmed in British Columba --  "Dead on Target" -- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075028/

Found a complete synopsis of "Dead on Target" at http://jabootu.net/?p=11826 -- NO beach scenes -- so it cannot have been that movie.

A low budget Bond style movie whch was intended as a pilot for a tv show (to rival UNCLE) which was not approved and so got released theatrically was "Agent for H.A.R.M."  Almost all of the movie is shot on location in Marina del Rey, CA, features a beach house, and lots of scenes just on the beach (even when the scene was meant to be in Eastern Europe). Was featured on M3TK -- maybe were questioner's friend actually watched the movie?    http://doubleosection.blogspot.lu/2010/04/movie-review-agent-for-h.html
